# SharePoint 2007, WSP solution is not deploying to Global Assembly Cache

Tags: 2007, solution-package, gac

I have a standard WSP package with a single assembly that is deployed to the GAC.

We have 2 versions of packages, both with the same assembly version and assembly file version.

Version 1 installs fine, deploying the assembly to gac.

Version 2 installs fine in test, however in production the assembly is not actually being deployed to the GAC on any of the WFE servers.

The ULS Logs contains the event saying "Deploying MyAssembly.dll to the GAC" but it never does.  When I redeploy the version 1 solution to production, it deploys to the GAC fine.

I have confirmed that when the package is removed the assembly is correctly removed from the global assembly cache.

Has anyone come across something like this before, what could be preventing our assembly from being deployed to the GAC?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually concluded that there must have been a reference between the two assemblies or this could not have happened.  We redeployed both WSP packages again and it is working sweet.

Lessons learnt were to formalise and test deployment processes, and to more vigilantly use labels and tags in source control to identify versions.